# ajax、jquery.dialog を使用したダイアログを表示させたい

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, eclipse, jsp

■問題
ajax通信により、サーバからレスポンスを受け取った後、jquery.dialog を使用したダイアログを表示させたいです。
以下ソースコードになります。

■実施した事
以下ソースコード(javascliptの.done(function(data){}部分)で、dialog が動作するか確認した所、ブラウザ上にダイアログは表示されず、管理ツール上でエラーが表示されていました。
この事象について、どなたか原因及び解決方法を教えて頂きたく思っております。
よろしくお願いします。

・エラー内容

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
```

・Javasclipt(抜粋)

```
j$("#reset").click(function (){
if (confirm("パスワードをリセットします。\nよろしいですか?")) {
var Id = j$("input[name='Id']").val();
j$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "./reset",
data : "Id=" + Id,
}).done(function(data){
$("#Sample_ID").dialog({
modal: true,
autoOpen: false,
title: 'ダイアログを表示',
});
$("#Sample_ID").dialog('open');
}).fail(function(){
alert("読み込み失敗");
});
}
});
```

・jsp(抜粋)

```
<div>
<c:if test="${customerInfo.authType == '01'}">
<%-- リセット機能 --%>
<input type="button" value="リセット" id="reset"></input>
</c:if>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery.dialog ということはjQueryUIのことですかね？きちんとjQueryUIは導入していますか？

Comment: 何度も確認しましたが、jQueryUIの導入はしていると思います。dialogのソースコードの記述が間違っているのでしょうか?

Comment: ドキュメント中に `id="Sample_ID"` を持った要素がありますか?

Comment: 問題点としてはJSPというよりもまずはHTML＋JSの問題かと思いますので、再現できるHTML＋JSコードを提示してもらえるとよいと思います。